# Exibir nome do usuário logado com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Como faço para exibir o nome do usuário logado no sistema?

**A função que faz a autenticação e cria a sessão é essa:**

```
function verificar()
{
    $this->load->model('tbdaluno');
    $check = $this->tbdaluno->validar();
    if($check)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('aluno', $check);
        redirect('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Eae amigo to com o  mesmo problema, conseguiu resolver? se sim nos ajude  a solucionar, preciso exibir o nome do usuario com a sessão também e não consigo. Abraço

Answer (score -1):

Dentro da sua condição de `if/else` cria uma variável para a `SESSION` que foi setada, e passa a variável no `$load`, ou de maneira bem rústica, na sua `View` use `$_SESSION['aluno']`.

```
function verificar()
{
    $this->load->model('tbdaluno');
    $check = $this->tbdaluno->validar();
    if($check)
    {
        $dados['aluno'] = $this->session->set_userdata('aluno', $check);
        redirect('dashboard',$dados);

    }
    else
    {
        redirect('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Correia de Andrade Poderia nos dar um exemplo?, sou iniciante em php codeigniter e to com o mesmo problema, preciso exibir o nome do usuario com sessão mas não consigo.

Comment: @Joana, a maneira que utilizei acima possibilita a utilização do $_SESSION na sua view... Exemplo no seu html da view, vai abrir a chamada php <?php echo $_SESSION['aluno']?>, desta maneira conseguirá mostrar na tela o usuário daquela sessão.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado, vou tentar aqui. Vlw